# How to get source line numbers in a specific revision of a file?

Tags: git, git-blame

It's possible to see ***source/original*** line numbers of lines with `git blame` But it shows line numbers according to the **last commit that made a modification in the line**

I want to do the same for a specific commit/revision of a file.

Example,

File: `file.ext` (**xyz11** is the revision/commit of the file we're currently reviewing)

Content:

```
Line 1 (**abc11** is the last commit changed this line)
Line 2 (**abc12** is the last commit changed this line)
Line 3 (**abc13** is the last commit changed this line)
```

I want to get **"3"** for **"Line 3"**. Git blame will show this info according to the **line's commit (abc13)** commit. But, since **xyz11** and **abc13** revisions contain different contents, actual line number in the **xyz11** may be different.

So how can I get line numbers in a specific revision of a file?

Note: I said **"source/original line number"** Because I want to get correct line numbers even if document is dirty (has uncommited changes) It is possible with `git blame`

My scenario is, I'll use these line numbers in API request to add inline comments

So, suppose I've modified the `file.ext`

```
Line 1
Line 2
Uncommited Line 
Uncommited Line
Line 3
```

I should get still **"3"** for **"Line 3"** instead of **"5"**, otherwise comment will go to wrong line. As I said, its possible with `git blame` but it shows this info according to the line's commit

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option **rev** for **git blame** so, you can specify the commit/revision you want to blame:

```
git blame <rev> file
```

### Example

```
git blame xyz11 file.txt
```

More info in the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame)

Comment: This seems what I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: @user3790180 please, if this worked for you, mark it as **accepted** (green checkmark ✓) and up vote it!! Thnx in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you have a file with uncommitted changes and your `git blame` looks like this.

```
$ git blame foo

^592c0a1 (Michael G. Schwern 2019-01-01 12:56:35 -0800 1) Line 1
^592c0a1 (Michael G. Schwern 2019-01-01 12:56:35 -0800 2) Line 2
00000000 (Not Committed Yet  2019-01-01 12:58:04 -0800 3) Uncommitted Line
00000000 (Not Committed Yet  2019-01-01 12:58:04 -0800 4) Uncommitted Line
^592c0a1 (Michael G. Schwern 2019-01-01 12:56:35 -0800 5) Line 3
```

Use `-n` to show what line it is in the original commit.

```
$ git blame -n foo

^592c0a1 1 (Michael G. Schwern 2019-01-01 12:56:35 -0800 1) Line 1
^592c0a1 2 (Michael G. Schwern 2019-01-01 12:56:35 -0800 2) Line 2
00000000 3 (Not Committed Yet  2019-01-01 12:58:47 -0800 3) Uncommitted Line
00000000 4 (Not Committed Yet  2019-01-01 12:58:47 -0800 4) Uncommitted Line
^592c0a1 3 (Michael G. Schwern 2019-01-01 12:56:35 -0800 5) Line 3
```

To ignore all uncommitted and unstaged changes, use `git blame <file> HEAD`. `HEAD` is the last commit. This will look for all changes to the file from `HEAD` backwards. Because intervening commits will also throw the line numbers off, you'll still want `-n` to get the line number in that commit. For example.

```
$ git blame -n foo

^592c0a1 1 (Michael G. Schwern 2019-01-01 12:56:35 -0800 1) Line 1
^592c0a1 2 (Michael G. Schwern 2019-01-01 12:56:35 -0800 2) Line 2
00000000 3 (Not Committed Yet  2019-01-01 13:03:06 -0800 3) Uncommitted line
4a87d48f 3 (Michael G. Schwern 2019-01-01 13:02:32 -0800 4) Line 2.5
^592c0a1 3 (Michael G. Schwern 2019-01-01 12:56:35 -0800 5) Line 3

$ git blame -n foo HEAD

^592c0a1 1 (Michael G. Schwern 2019-01-01 12:56:35 -0800 1) Line 1
^592c0a1 2 (Michael G. Schwern 2019-01-01 12:56:35 -0800 2) Line 2
4a87d48f 3 (Michael G. Schwern 2019-01-01 13:02:32 -0800 3) Line 2.5
^592c0a1 3 (Michael G. Schwern 2019-01-01 12:56:35 -0800 4) Line 3
```

Comment: Combination of this (`-n` parameter) and @Josué Cortina 's answer seems what I'm looking for. Thanks